# Who ultimately receives principal and interest of a mortgage payment?

Tags: mortgage, security

So the mortgage is bundled and sold as a securitized instrument in tranches, etc. That explains the **contract** side of a mortgage. When an individual makes a monthly payment on that mortgage, how does the money for that specific mortgage find its way to its rightful creditor? This question is about the **money** side of a mortgage backed security.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The money is paid to investors who bought those mortgage backed securities. The company that services those loans is responsible for making sure the money is paid to the right investors

Comment: And the servicing company takes a little cut?  But the investor is okay with that because they don't have to service it or handle phone calls?

Comment: yes, the investors also lower the risk by spreading the risk over multiple mortgages.